# Работа с типам в TS

Tags: typescript, vue3

Всем привет.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в TS правильно обьявить переменную предназначенную для хранения масива данных.

Вопрос прост, но проблема в следующем...
Переменная должна в себе содержать вопросы. Вопрос может быть один или несколько. Каждый вопрос - новый блок на странице сайта.

По умолчанию изначально вопросов на экране быть не должно.
Т.е. массив questions должжен быть пуст.

Но, я не могу просто обьявить что-то вроде

```
const arrQuestions = ref([])
```

И потом сделать push эллемента, все поля будут заполнены. Я не могу - ошибка.

Как вариант изначально заполнить массив questions одним объектом, тогда в этот массив можно черещз push ложить еще объекты. Но такой вариан не подходит, так как тогда в массиве есть 1 эллемент и он оно бражается на странице...

Как сделать так, чтобы в массив можно было ложить обьекты определенного типа с нуля через пуш ?

Comment: Как-то так `const arrQuestions = ref([] as Question[])`

Comment: Хотя, а что такое `ref`?

Comment: ref - это из vue.
там так переменные обворачиваются

Comment: @AlexeyTen попробовал Ваш вариант. Теперь пропали методы массивов :( Без указания типа VSCode обозначает переменную как Ref<never[]> с типом примерно вот так Ref<{ свойства: типы ...}>

Comment: Ну тогда стоит читать [документацию](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-ref) `const arrQuestions = ref<Question[]>([])`

Comment: А квадратные скобки вы не забыли?

Comment: @AlexeyTen да куда я только не пробовал квадратные скобки ставить :) Если есделсть без ref.     const questions : JsonRro[] = [], то так рабоатет, но я теряю реактивность. Переменные, не обернутые в ref по vue не реактивны.

Comment: @AlexeyTen удивительно, но ваш совет помог. Странно, я вроде такой вариант испытывал, видимо где-то ошибся в другом месте изначальн. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Пример компонента

```
<template>
 <span>{{ questions.length }}</span>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import { ref } from 'vue';
  
  interface Question {
    prop1: string;
    //...
    propN: boolean;
  }
  
  const questions = ref<Question[]>([]);
  
  function addQuestion() {
    questions.value.push({
      prop1: 'some string';
      //...
      propN: true;
    });
  }
</script>
```